# What exactly do this code snippet?

Tags: perl, moose

What exactly do this code snippet?

```
...
method go() {
    my %args;
    while ( ref( $_[0] ) eq 'HASH' ) {
        %args = ( %args, %{ shift(@_) } );
    }
    ....
}
```

Taken from a Moose based package...
While the first argument is a hashref, do what? (with the shifted out hashref?)
I understand shift(@_) simply dont understand what's mean the

```
%hash = (%hash, %{$hashref});
```

Comment: Also note that beyond the `method` keyword from I assume MooseX::Declare, there is nothing Moose specific in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the first element of `@_` is a reference to a hash, add the contents of that hash reference to the hash `%args` and remove the reference from `@_`. In other words, consolidate all of the initial hash arguments into a single hash.

`%a = (%a, %b)` for some pair of hashes `%a` and `%b` is analogous to `@a = (@a, @b)` for some pair of arrays `@a` and `@b`, joining `@a` and `@b` into a single list and assigning the result back to `@a`. For arrays, there is of course a shorthand `push @a, @b` for just this purpose.

Comment: so %hash3 = (%hash1, %hash2) mean merging two hashes? Seem need perldoc perlreftut perldata ;)

Comment: Thanx. Sometimes Perl is more powerful as me expecting. ;)

Comment: @jm666 - also note that same key repeated end up with last value in merged hash. It is often used idiom for giving default value for named parameters: `my %args = (name => 'default', @_);`